# How to change breaks to spaces while typing in textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

I'm trying to change breaks (enter) to spaces in my textarea while typing. That's meant that when I'm typing in textarea and click enter, not a new line appears but just a space. It is possible to do ti?

Comment: This is very bad for the usability, why do you want this?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Good luck googling javascript onkeydown etc.

Comment: hot to change it with onkeydown?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by adding an `onchange` event to your text area that updates it's value, if you like this to happen while the user is typing you can use the `onkeyup` event.

the code would look like this.

```
textarea.onchange = function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\n/g, ' ');;
}
```

code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amdorra/fABxL/)

Comment: this code don't work in chrome v23 and IE10

Comment: you could use `addEventListener` instead of `onchange`